# Giving colour to the alternate cells in table view in xcode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I want to give alternate colors to my table view cell. e.g first cell color remains white while the next cell is light gray ,then third again white ,then next is again light gray and so on.Can anyone tell me the method to do it please.

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `cell:(UITableviewCell*) forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath` Data source method insert this test:

```
NSUinteger row=indexPath.row;
if (row % 2==0)
 cell.contentView.backGroundColor=[UIColor blueClor] ;
else
 cell.contentView.backGroundColor=[UIColor whiteClor] ;
```

Answer (score 8):

use this christy:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row%2 == 0) {
        UIColor *altCellColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:100 green:10 blue:10 alpha:1];
        cell.backgroundColor = altCellColor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hii Christina :

Check this out,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ((indexPath.row % 2) == 0) {

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            }
    else {

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightgrayColor];
        }
}
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code when you create the `UITableViewCell`.

```
if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
{
    myCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
else if(indexPath.row % 2 == 1)
{
    myCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing an '='. Should be `if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Christy in much generic way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 ? [UIColor lightGrayColor] : [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```